# How do you write the method and pagination in the same line in Codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, methods, codeigniter-4

Hello i have a trouble here, so i have this controller

```
public function komik()
{
    $data = [
        'title' => 'komik learn',
        'komik' => $this->komikModel->getKomikAll(),
        'koikkreguler' => $this->komikModel->getKomikReguler(),
        'komikplus' => $this->komikModel->getKomikPlus()
    ];
   
    return view('komik/index', $data);
}
```

And i want to give a pagination to 'komik','komikreguler', 'komikplus'. but each of this group needs to call the method. i tried to figure it out, maybe... but i have no clue at all. someone can help? thank you

```
'komik' => $this->komikModel->getKomikAll()*what i tried ->pagination(4)*
```